# Let $x_0$ $\in \space G$, G is open, and put $F=[x_0,\infty) \cap G^c.$ (a) Prove that $F$ is a non-empty set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let G be a non-empty open subset of $ \mathbb{R}$.

Let $x_0$ $\in \space G$ and put $F=[x_0,\infty) \cap G^c.$ Here $[x_0,\infty)=\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}:x \geq x_0  \rbrace $.

(a) Prove that $F$ is a non-empty set.

My attempt:

I found a counter example. If $G= \mathbb{R}-\lbrace 0 \rbrace $ then $G$ is clearly open. However, if $x_0 =5$ for example, then we have F=$\emptyset$.

Yet, the exercise claims that this is never true.

Please help! Thank you very much

Comment: Your counterexample clearly works, so something's wrong with this exercise. Maybe you are supposed to be using an alternative topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @akkkk I dont think so, its an intro course to real analysis, so basic stuff mostly, probably a mistake with the exercise thanks a lot!